# jogl list all graphics devices

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl

I've just recently started to use JOGL and my first program fails because I cannot get GL4 profile.

```
GLProfile test = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4);
```

This line fails with error message `Profile GL4 is not available on null`. `GL3bc` works fine. I suspect that the problem is the program is trying to use built-in Intel HD graphics (which might not have support for GL4) instead of NVIDIA graphic card so now I'm looking for a way to change default graphic device but I cannot find anything useful.
`GLProfile.get()` has an overload which accepts `AbstractGraphicsDevice` but I cannot figure out how to get an instance corresponding to the NVIDIA card. I think there has to be some way to list all the devices available. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can select it through jogl.

I know you can select it thorugh the nvidia panel

[image]

If you don't want to select it globally, you should be use the "Program Settings" tab instead